# Iterate over String.prototype

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I am aware that the `for in` loop can help iterate through properties of objects, prototypes and collections.

The fact is, I need to iterate over `String.prototype`, and though `console.log(String.prototype)` displays the complete prototype, when I do

```
for (var prop in String.prototype) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

to display the name of the elements in the prototype, it displays nothing, as if it were empty.

Do the JavaScript engines hide the basic prototypes methods, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @pimvdb: Darn; beat me to it.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: The editing or the answer? :)

Comment: @pimvdb: The former of course!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Helps me learn best practices!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specification says:

> If the value of an attribute is not explicitly specified by this specification for a named property, the default value defined in Table 7 is used.
>
> Table 7 — Default Attribute Values
>
> ...
>
> [[Enumerable]] false

So it is not enumerable (as with all built-in properties).

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, all properties in String.prototype are non-enumerable. To get a list of all the properties, including non-enumerable, use  [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) (newer browsers only)

Answer (score 1):

Native methods aren't visible through an `for(prop in obj)` iteration.

It's possible to find properties when you loop through a built-in object. In this case, the page has extended the prototype with a custom method. Frameworks (such as jQuery) often modify built-in objects in this way.