# Why "for-in" loop doesn't iterate through the prototype properties?

Tags: javascript

Let's create a new object:

```
var dict = {};
```

Known fact is that after creating a new object, this new object inherits the `Object.prototype` . So when I try to check if the prototype's properties were inherited I do `"toString" in obj` for which I get `true`. But when I want to put all the properties of the newly created object into an array I would see that the array is empty after finishing filling up. Have a look on the code below:

```
var names = [];

for (var name in dict) {
  names.push(name);
}; 
names.length;
```

Fail to see why it happens.

Comment: Because they are not enumerable.

Comment: Not all properties are enumerable (you can create non-enumerable properties yourself using property descriptors). This means you can access them by name, but not list them.

Comment: Here's a proof-link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770869/iterate-over-string-prototype

Comment: Rather than a `for...in loop` you should just use `Object.keys(dict).forEach()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As many said in the comments, the For-In loop enumerates only the enumerable properties in the prototype chain, and the inherited `toString` property is not enumerable.

If you want to iterate through the non-enumerable properties of the `object` prototype to see if "ToString" is there then you should get the object prototype and get its enumerable and non-enumerable properties using the `getOwnPropertyNames` method:

```
var dict = {};
var objPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(dict);

var propertyNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objPrototype);

propertyNames.length;
```

Comment: or just `var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(objPrototype)` - forget the OP's loop - it just confuses the issue.

Comment: Right :).. i wasnt even looking.. its late, i should go to sleep!